# Embedding Times New Roman in XSL-FOP

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I recently discovered that the commercial printing company that my office uses does not have referenced fonts on their printers.  The PDFs I produce using the Apache FOP Library by default set fonts to referenced during the XSL-FO transformation.  Three of the standard fonts (Times New Roman, Courier and DejaVu) will not embed despite my efforts to force them. I have tried everything on this [link](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html) and even the older method described [here](http://www.casabac.com/pdf/CasabacInfoFOPFontEmbedding.pdf). Thank you in advance for any input you can provide.

Example of my attempts to modify the fop.xconf

```
<font embed-url="file:///C:/WINNT/Fonts/TIMES.TTF">
    <font-triplet name="Times Embed" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
</font>
<font embed-url="file:///C:/WINNT/Fonts/TIMESI.TTF">
    <font-triplet name="Times Embed I" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
</font>   

<!-- Times Roman -->
<font>
  <afp-font name="Times Roman" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
    <afp-raster-font size="6" characterset="C0N20060" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="7" characterset="C0N20070" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="8" characterset="C0N20080" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="9" characterset="C0N20090" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="10" characterset="C0N20000" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="11" characterset="C0N200A0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="12" characterset="C0N200B0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="14" characterset="C0N200D0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="16" characterset="C0N200F0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="18" characterset="C0N200H0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="20" characterset="C0N200J0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="24" characterset="C0N200N0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="30" characterset="C0N200T0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
    <afp-raster-font size="36" characterset="C0N200Z0" base14-font="TimesRoman"/>
  </afp-font>
    <font-triplet name="Times" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="TimesRoman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="Times Roman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="Times-Roman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="Times New Roman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="TimesNewRoman" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="serif" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>
```

Comment: A commercial printing company doesn't have Times New Roman or Courier fonts?

Comment: Yes, each font has to be licensed and the printers see it as a cost cutting measure to require embedded fonts.

Comment: @eabraham there is nothing to embed... IIRC there are 14 fonts defined in the PDF standard which only get embedded in extremely exceptional cases... these fonts must be present at printing company !

Comment: The printing company doesn't support the standard.  As ridiculous as it sounds this is the obstacle I have to overcome.

Comment: @eabraham, must they receive a pdf? I have an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they do not have to receive a "pdf" per se, you can convert it to PCL, which is nothing more than a description of how to print the file. According to wikipedia it is the "DeFacto standard for printer languages." Ghostscript can do this for you http://www.ghostscript.com/ its free open source etc. etc...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghostscript/forums/forum/5451/topic/3096129 -- helpful instructions on how to do the pdf to pcl conversion :)

I hope this is helpful, i feel your pain :)